# Are PHP closures broken or am I missing something?

Tags: php, closures

I've been reading on the new features of PHP 5.3, and one of the major features are *closures*.

Unless I'm very badly mistaken, the PHP developers are either:
a) confusing closures with just anonymous functions
b) the closures are broken in PHP 5.3.1 in which I'm testing

From [what wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) closures are the mechanism of anonymous functions plus the binding of the function's parent's scope variables to the function's scope. The last part seems broken in PHP.

I've checked PHP bugs, and found nothing about this, strangely.

Here's how I'm testing:

```
<?php

function getFun() {
    $x = 2;
    return function() {
        return $x;
    };
}
$f = getFun(); // getFun()(); doesn't work -.-
var_dump($f()); // $f() == null
```

In languages that actually implement closures, it returns 2:

```
def f():
    x = 2
    return lambda: x
print(f()()) # prints 2
```

and

```
alert((function() {
    var x = 2;
    return function() {
        return x;
    };
})()()); // alerts 2
```

So, am I wrong or?

Comment: I don't have the new php to test :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

variables inherited from the outer scope need to be listed explicitely.  from the manual:

```
public function getTotal($tax)
{
    $total = 0.00;

    $callback =
        function ($quantity, $product) use ($tax, &$total)
...
```

Comment: i'd call it explicit closure variable identification, not a fudge.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into this in a bit more detail, and apparently the use thing is just copying variables and not actually binding them to the scope. So unless you use &$tax (by refference), if you change the tax after the anonymous function creation, you are going to get the old value from the previously created function. PHP actually just fakes closures by copying vars instead of actually binding them to the scopes.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's implementation of closures is slightly different from what you might expect if you're used to using JavaScript.  Simply calling `function () { return x; }` won't work as you must take advantage of the `use` statement.